# Iterate a stats function over a row of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, statistics

I have a dataframe that looks like the  table below.  I want to create a new row called Ploss is the Normal Distribution function using Return as the mean and the Vol row as the standard deviation.

Here is the function call I tried Ploss=NormalDist(df.loc['Return'], df.loc['Vol']).cdf(0).  But I get an error when I try to do this.  It complains that the sigma must be greater than zero, which it is.  When I just try to call with simple numbers it works fine - so Ploss=NormalDist(.11,.14).cdf(0) works fine.

```
         Iter1  Iter2   Iter3   Iter4   Iter5   Iter6   Iter7   Iter8   Iter9   Iter10
Return   0.04    0.05    0.06    0.07    0.08    0.09    0.10    0.10    0.10    0.11 
Vol      0.01    0.02    0.04    0.05    0.07    0.08    0.10    0.11    0.13    0.14
```

Comment: As a follow on, how would I construct a lambda formula to calculate the Value at Risk at a 0.01 level where the formula is var01=norm.ppf(.01,mu,sigma) where mu is in the Return row and sigma is in the Vol row?

I tried dff.apply(lambda x: norm.ppf(0.01,*x) axis=0) but that said invalid syntax, perhaps you forgot a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statistics import NormalDist

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((2, 10)), index=['Return', 'Vol'])

df.apply(lambda x: NormalDist(*x).cdf(0), axis=0)
```

Out:

```
0    2.215590e-01
1    1.091426e-02
2    4.853840e-01
3    8.792580e-03
4    2.487104e-01
5    4.982243e-01
6    1.533436e-04
7    1.215330e-01
8    9.739128e-10
9    0.000000e+00
dtype: float64
```